# How to sort a list in descending order for the first criteria and ascending order for the second criteria?

Tags: python, sorting, sortedlist

I know that you can sort a list using multiple criterias with the sort or sorted functions, like this:

```
list = sorted(list, key=lambda x:(x[0], x[1]))
```

The code above sorts the list in ascending order and only if the first parameter is equal to another element, the list is sorted in an ascending order following the second criteria.

If you include the parameter `reverse=True`, it will do the same as I said above, but the list will be sorted in an descending order in both criterias.

That's not what I want though. I'd like to sort the list in an descending order and if there are equal elements, then the tuple will be sorted in an ascending order by the second element.

For example,
this code:

```
list = [(99, 41), (85, 33), (99, 28)]
list = sorted(list, key=lambda x:(x[0], x[1]), reverse=True)
print(list)
```

prints [(99, **41**), (99, **28**), (85, 33)]
but I want to be printed: [(99, **28**), (99, **41**), (85, 33)]

Comment: how about changing the sign in your key function ? would that work ?

Comment: Avoid using builtins as variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, maybe that helps:

It works because your items are *tuples* so we use the tricks to sort them by desc/asceding order differently.
So the first will be descending order,  and 2nd ascending as it shown.

Notes - please don't use Python *built-in* as the variable names.

```
>>> L =  [(99, 41), (85, 33), (99, 28)]
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))
[(99, 28), (99, 41), (85, 33)]

>>> A = [(12, 22), (13, 33), (12, 12), (13, 3)]
>>> A.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))      # in-place sort
>>> 
>>> A
[(13, 3), (13, 33), (12, 12), (12, 22)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> new_list = sorted(list, key=lambda x:(x[0], 1/x[1]), reverse=True)
>>> print(new_list)
[(99, 28), (99, 41), (85, 33)]
```

This lambda function orders in ascending order but not based on x[0] and x[1], but in x[0] and 1/x[1]

1/x[1] is simply the inverse of x[1] which will be smaller as x[1] gets bigger

**For example:**

- 1/28 = 0.03571
- 1/33 = 0.03030
- 1/48 = 0.02083

Comment: Why would you do that and risk a division by zero error instead of negate like everybody else?

Comment: Sorry, that was my first approach. But you're totally right.

Comment: Also, `1/7014398509481988 == 1/7014398509481989`, so you'd treat those two ints as equal. Don't know what the smallest example is, probably not much smaller, so maybe not relevant. But negation avoids that issue, too.